# Permanent install

Tags: system-installation

Sorry for the obtuse title, but this might be a bit unusual.

I set EOS up on a Samsung USB/SSD for my desktop a while back. I've been using it (and tweaking) for a while and it works well.

The desktop has Win10 installed on the internal drive.

I've gotten to the point where I would like to migrate the Samsung installation to the internal drive.

Any thoughts on the simplest way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Without knowing more about your hardware, I would assume that the simplest way to do this would be to remove the SSD device from the USB caddy and install it as an internal storage device. This would save all sorts of time and hassle. If the SSD in the USB caddy is a standard 2.5” or NVMe device, then you may even be able to put the Win10 disk in there and keep it in case there are files you haven’t backed up completely 